# Getting the frameset name

Tags: designer, formula, lotus-domino, lotus

I have a computed field on a page in a frame, I need the field to change values depending on the frameset name. Or if there's some other way to do this it would be nice too.

Thank you, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer since you didn't gave enough detail.
I make the assertion that it is a web application:
you have a form displayed in a frame (frame or iframe?), client side you should do something like:
[How to access parent Iframe from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript)
or [Can't access content of another frame in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777289/cant-access-content-of-another-frame-in-chrome)
Then if you need to display *depending* of the frameset: put in hidden field the *different* options. Dynamically display depending of the value you get client side.

Comment: It's a client application, the computed field is placed in a Page that is placed in a Frame of a frameset. The app will never go online or be displayed in a browser.